# how to set windows 7 lock screen input language

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, language

it seems that welcome screen and lock screen are two different things and have separate input language settings. If I use control panel / keyboard and languages and copy settings to set it  for the welcome screen it does not change the input language when I just lock the screen for current user. I thought when you lock the screen it has the same keyboard chosen as you had in a system before locking, but not, it has always the one which I don't want...

Answer (score 1):

When you set this in the Control Panel > Open Change keyboards or other input methods within Region and Language.

When in there you should see the Administrative tab on this tab you have Welcome screen and new user accounts. You can then copy current language settings to a new user account. This then applies the settings are used during the login process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, it does not help at all. Please read again what I am asking instead of copypasting the generic solution ;) Thanks

Comment: it seems that lock screen keyboard is always set to whatever is set as a Default input language in Text services and Input Languages. I admit it may be strange but some people learnt to type their password on an english keyboard but they work with czech keyboard, thus this can be a problem for them.

Comment: Hmm I have Windows 7 VDI's rolled out across 6 countries and I do not get the same behaviour as you. Is it a machine on a Domain or just a stand alone workstation/laptop?

Comment: stand alone laptop. I also tried it on a VirtualBox VM. How exactly does it behave to you if differently then what I described in last comment?

Comment: Just to confirm your users see a QWERTY keyboard (for example) no matter what region settings are in Windows so if they are set to French region you still get a QWERTY keyboard instead of a AZERTY keyboard on logon screen?

One thing I do have on my infrastructure which might be why I'm seeing a difference to yourself is my regions are set by group policy. Although the group policy is a user policy I use Group Policy Loop Back Setting so its seen as a computer policy hence applied during boot which might give me the correct keyboard (this is not confirmed just an after thought).